# Adding global object to rusty_v8 using serde_v8

Tags: rust

I'm working on a Rust application that uses rusty_v8 to implement a scripting capability.  I would like to be able to add a struct to the v8's global context, but am stuck on how to do so.  I found serde_v8, but I'm not sure it's still supported and I can't get the serde_v8::to_v8 call to work (it doesn't like scope)

As a workaround, I am able to inject a "let x = (JSON representation);" to the compiled code, but I'd really like to set the global value, if at all possible.

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
    struct Test {
        foo: u32
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_using_let_workaround() {
        let platform = v8::new_default_platform(0, false).make_shared();
        v8::V8::initialize_platform(platform);
        v8::V8::initialize();
    
        let isolate = &mut v8::Isolate::new(Default::default());
        let scope = &mut v8::HandleScope::new(isolate);
        let global = v8::ObjectTemplate::new(scope);

        // Create test object
        let test = Test { foo: 100 };
        let test_as_string = serde_json::to_string(&test).unwrap();


        let context = v8::Context::new_from_template(scope, global);
        let scope = &mut v8::ContextScope::new(scope, context);
        let code = format!("let test = {}; test.foo", test_as_string);
        let v8_code = v8::String::new(scope, &code).unwrap();
        let script = v8::Script::compile(scope, v8_code, None).unwrap();
        let result = script.run(scope).unwrap();

        let answer = result.to_rust_string_lossy(scope);

        assert_eq!(answer, "100");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_using_global() {
        let platform = v8::new_default_platform(0, false).make_shared();
        v8::V8::initialize_platform(platform);
        v8::V8::initialize();
    
        let isolate = &mut v8::Isolate::new(Default::default());
        let scope = &mut v8::HandleScope::new(isolate);
        let global = v8::ObjectTemplate::new(scope);

        // Create test object
        let test = Test { foo: 100 };
        let test_as_string = serde_json::to_string(&test).unwrap();
        
        // Next line complains about scope: "mismatched types
        //     expected mutable reference `&mut HandleScope<'_>`
        //     found mutable reference `&mut HandleScope<'_, ()>`""
        // let testAsV8 = serde_v8::to_v8(scope, test); 
        
        // global.set(
        //      v8::String::new(scope, "test").unwrap().into(),
        //      testAsV8.unwrap().into() // --<< something like this???
        // );

        let context = v8::Context::new_from_template(scope, global);
        let scope = &mut v8::ContextScope::new(scope, context);
        let code = "test.foo";
        let v8_code = v8::String::new(scope, code).unwrap();
        let script = v8::Script::compile(scope, v8_code, None).unwrap();
        let result = script.run(scope).unwrap();

        let answer = result.to_rust_string_lossy(scope);

        assert_eq!(answer, "100");
    }
```